# PrettyPhoto Lightbox Jumps Around the Page When Transitioning Between Photos

Tags: wordpress, lightbox, prettyphoto

Using a theme that has Prettyphoto used by the developer. Experiencing an issue I can't find any threads on: the lightbox frame jumps all over the page - left, right, up, down, center - when clicking throughout the photos. Never quite know where it'll end up on the page when you go to the next photo.

Have a look for yourselves here: http://www.davidplusmissy.com/photos/

I read specifying a Doctype should resolve issues like this, however, it did not help. And there's no forums I can find discussing this specific issue.

Any ideas? Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 0):

Try to turn of the css animation converter for jQuery: jquery.animate-enhanced

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.davidplusmissy.com/wp-content/themes/revera/js/lib/jquery.animate-enhanced.min.js?ver=4.1.4"></script>
```

it can conflict with prettyPhoto.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove:

```
jquery.animate-enhanced.min.js
```

Comment: a little explaination why this will fix the OP's problem could help him more on the long run.